# Find all the bijective functions $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ such that $x=\frac{1}{2}\big(f(x)+f^{-1}(x)\big)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse, functional-equations, inverse-function

> Find all bijective functions $ f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ that satisfy the equation $$x=\frac{1}{2} \big(f(x) +f^{-1} (x)\big)\,\forall x \in[0,1]\,.$$

I honestly don't know how to approach this. I tried to plug in different values, but this doesn't work.

Comment: So $f(x)=x$ obviously does the trick. I think it might be the only the continuous function that does this but I don't know how to prove this at first glance. Do we know anything else about the function? A bijection isn't a lot of power over a function. There are many bizarre bijections. Is this question from a text? from a class?

Comment: What if $F(0,x) := x$ and $F(n,x)=f(F(n-1,x))$ for all integer $n$ and real $x$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $x \in I = [0, 1]$ and $f(x) = x + a$. The only way this can work is if $f^{-1}(x) = x - a$ (and in particular $x - a$ is also in $I$), so we also get $f(x - a) = x$.

Looking at this as $f(x - a) = (x - a) + a$, we can apply the result above with $x - a$ instead of $x$, which tell us that $f(x - 2a) = x - a$. Repeating this process, $f(x - na) = x - (n - 1)a$ for any integer $n \ge 0$.

In particular, $x - na \in I$ for all $n$. But $I$ is bounded above and below, which means that $a = 0$: otherwise the value $x - na$ will eventually wander out of $I$ for some large $n$ and we will get a contradiction.

So we have shown that $a = 0$ for any choice of $x$, which means that $f(x) = x$ always, and the identity function is the only solution.

(Note that we did not need to assume $f$ is continuous.)

Comment: Nice solution, thank you! When you choose $a$ at the beginning of your soltuion, is it a constant or can it also be a function?

Comment: @JustAnUser. Say you map some value $x$ in the interval to $f(x)$. We let $a=x-f(x)$. A little magic happens and then we conclude that $a=0$. It's just a constant.

Comment: By the way, @JustAnUser, I found it very helpful to draw pictures of what the graph of $f$ would look like in different cases. I was too lazy to illustrate the proof, but that's where the proof came from, so you might try that too.